# Sending External Emails From Apache James Server

Tags: java, james

I have created users on my local Apache James Server. I can send e-mails from my Java Spring code and it works, but when sending to an external e-mail address I get the following exception on the server:

james.mailetcontext | Temporary exception delivering mail

Am I missing something that I need to set? I am using Apache James Server 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localhost can't send e-mail. Try upload the code on server with smtp active, and it should work.
E-mail aways test on-line, local don't work.

Comment: How can you upload the code? The localhost server is running.

Comment: Are you using it on your own machine? You need online server with apache fully configurable to test send e-mail